# Encryption Key Management during a asynchronous call for a short-lived key

Tags: asynchronous, encryption, cryptography, ecdh

Below is the scenario I need to manage. Any thoughts on best ways to manage the  encryption keys are highly appreciated.

Bob, the client needs to pull some confidential data from Alice, the data provider. Bob and Alice agree to use Elliptic Curve Delffie-Hellman key exchange agreement. So, whenever Bob requests some data from Alice, secret key exchange using ECDH happens first. Post that Alice will prepare the data, which takes few seconds to few minutes to complete. Once the data is ready, Alice encrypts the data using the symmetric key derived from ECDH key exchange and sends the notification to Bob to pull the data. Using a call back API Bob pulls the data from Alice and decrypts using the secret key. Post this secret key generated as part of ECDH is destroyed as the requirement is that key needs to be Ephemeral.

So the question I have is, what is the best and practical way to safe keep the secret key at Bob's end for few seconds to few minutes while he waits for the data to arrive after the initial data request and ECDH key exchange?  Important to note that Bob can either send such request for data from a mobile app or from a web browser on any supported device.

Using one of the Key Management Systems out there sounds like an option. But given that key is very short-lived as the requirement is to have a new key for every transaction and there could be 100s of such transaction every day, not sure if it is financially prudent and practical to rely on a KMS in this scenario.

Note that, for certain reasons, process of data request and fulfilment, and the encryption algorithm explained above are non negotiable.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to re-implement a part of TLS yourself? Just use it and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you @ArtjomB.

I understand that the DH key exchange is also used at TLS level. But, in my case I am mandated to have an end-to-end encryption on data layer, in addition to the network layer encryption provided by TLS 1.3 (This is what I mean - https://cyware.com/news/transport-layer-encryption-and-end-to-end-encryption-whats-the-difference-between-them-d90f6d6a). So, here I am referring to the data layer E2E encryption. Key will be generated using ECDH and AES256 algorithm will be used for the data encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bob needs access to the key in order to decrypt the data he should store it in such a way that does not undermine the storage of the data that the key protects. It means that the key could be either held in memory if the data must only live in memory when it is received. The key can be stored when the data it protects must also be stored.

Keep in mind that you can re-engineer this "problem" through an additional encryption layer which moves the problem from Bob to Alice. Alice generates a random key, encrypts the data with it and stores the ciphertext on a public location (API). Then the key exchange happens which results in a second key. The second key is used to encrypt the first key and send that to Bob. Now Bob can decrypt the data as soon as the encrypted first key is received.